# Cannot get the additional detail i.e account id from session callback using Next_auth

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I want to extract account id as additional detail from session callback using Next_auth. Whatevere I add in jwt token and pass it to session callback still it returns the same data. I tried logging out and loggin in many times but all in vain. Any help will be appreciated.

Code in pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";

export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        authorization: {
            params: {
              prompt: "consent",
              access_type: "offline",
              response_type: "code"
            }
        }
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET
    })
  ],
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  session:{
    strategy:"jwt"
  },
  callback: {
    async jwt({ token, account, user }) {
      // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
      if (user) {
        token.id = account.id;
      }
      return token
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.
      session.user.id = token.id;
      return session;
    },
    // redirect: async(url, _baseUrl) => {
    //     if (url === "/profile") {
    //         return Promise.resolve("/");
    //     }
    //     return Promise.resolve("/");
    // }
  }
})
```

Code in login page

```
import { useSession, getSession, signIn } from "next-auth/react"
useEffect(() => {
      const good = async () => {
        const session = await getSession();
        if (session) {
            console.log(session);
        }
      }
      good();
    }, [])
```

Result I get is

```
{"user":{"name":"myname","email":"myemail","image":"imageUrl"},"expires":"2022-09-05T11:28:41.840Z"}
```

Comment: did you try `token.id = user.id` ?

Comment: @mocherfaoui I figured out I had written callback instead of callbacks. That's why it was'nt making any changes